# Ruby On Rails Excel Import Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I am working on ruby on rails platform. I am doing excel import with Roo package with following code

```
def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
      when '.xls' then
        Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
      when '.xlsx' then
        Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
      else
        raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
```

The code is working fine on production until I did bundle update command on production and after this I get error for importing Excel with above code is
Wrong number of arguments ( 3 for 1..2) for `Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)` please suggest how the working code gets such a error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please format your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 Roo::Excelx.new(file.path,options={})
```

Comment: Hi I did a change in code as Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, packed: nil, file_warning: :ignore) and it is working fine, but I want to find why the previous code which is working before bundle update command execution and suddenly gets such a error.

Comment: The changes happened while updating the Roo gem are mentioned here here. https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md